# How do I resolve an npm peerinvalid error when the versions do not actually conflict?

Tags: npm

Trying to install `ngmin-webpack-plugin`, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package webpack does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular-webpack-plugin@0.0.1 wants webpack@~1.1.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer webpack-dev-server@1.4.6 wants webpack@1.x
```

Notice that the `1.x` and `~1.1.0` version requirements do not actually conflict.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This is a confusing error message. It's not saying that `angular-webpack-plugin` and `webpack-dev-server` conflict with each other—it's saying that `webpack` conflicts with those two!

I'm not sure why that would happen though since `ngmin-webpack-plugin` doesn't have a dependency on webpack, and I'm able to install all three happily. Are you sure the installation of `ngmin-webpack-plugin` is what's causing the issue?

Comment: I was having similar issues until I ran an `npm update npm -g`. Have you tried updating npm?

Comment: updating npm also fixed this for me

Answer (score 0):

As noted by matthewwithanm, the problem lies with the version of `webpack` I have installed: `webpack@1.3.4` is not compatible with `angular-webpack-plugin`'s requirement on `~1.1.0`.

The fix, in my case, was updating `angular-webpack-plugin` which has an update webpack version requirement.